# Laravel if error page, then redirect back

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, controller

I am going to try to public my **laravel** project,
but sometimes since i cant test all the step cases so it may encounter error with a whole page of error message

> How can i redirect back if encounter error?  at least it can avoid
>   user experience losing, i dont want users able to see the error
>   message

(it is better if it can automatic report to my server with error message) but at least dont let user see the error page

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your `.env` file on the production server, you can set `APP_DEBUG=false`.

> The debug option in your `config/app.php` configuration file
>   determines how much information about an error is actually displayed
>   to the user. By default, this option is set to respect the value of
>   the `APP_DEBUG` environment variable, which is stored in your .env
>   file.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#error-detail)

If you want to redirect user on exceptions then you can do this in the `render()` method of `App\Exceptions\Handler` class

For example:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
        return redirect()->to('your_url');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#render-method)

To send error messages on your email you can use this github [repo](https://github.com/squareboat/sneaker).

Comment: how to use the render function?   in controller?

Comment: You can't use render function in the controller. It is the method of `App\Exceptions\Handler` class which is triggered whenever an exception is thrown. Read the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#render-method)

Comment: @AmitGupta can i send error msg to mail and redirect error page to home page simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your config file, config/app.php and make debug to false

Documentation: [Laravel Errors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors)